# COUNTIF() with output list of INDEX()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two dynamic arrays which I want to get the common values from. One of the arrays is being built with a `INDEX()` which gives me the following data quite nicely:

[image]

When wrapping this in a `COUNTIF` I get presented with an array with errors:

[image]

How would I go about doing this? My resulting formula looks like this:

`=COUNTIF(INDEX('DATAMODEL - Prod spec attr'!A:A, FILTER(ROW(INDEX('DATAMODEL - Prod spec attr'!$G$3:$JE$405,0,ROW())), INDEX('DATAMODEL - Prod spec attr'!$G$3:$JE$405,0,ROW())=TRUE)), 'CS - Prod Spec Attr'!G:G)`

The end goal is wrapping this all up in a `FILTER()` to get only the common values in both arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue you are experiencing is that `COUNTIF()` does not take an array where a range is expected.

Try something along these lines:

```
=LET(_arr1,<Functions_to_get_arr1>,TOCOL(IFS(XMATCH(_arr1,<Functions_to_get_arr2>),_arr1),3))
```